# How to use google sheet as database for my Android app with appscript deployment as "any one with google account."

Tags: android, google-apps-script

I used a google sheet to store my Android app data so that multiple users can access the same from different mobile phones. But, from what learned from youtube classes, I always deployed appscript access as "anyone". Is there any issue with such open access? If yes, can I use the other deployment option "Any one with Google account" and how to use the url in my app?
Currently I just copy paste the url to the app by deploying without any restriction.

the url from Appscript is stored in Strings as a variable url.

in App>

```
String getMember_url=url+"action=getMember";
            StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, getMember_url,
            new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response)
                {
                    
                    findMemberandShow(response);
                }
            },

            new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

                    
                }
            }
    );

    int socketTimeOut = 50000;
    RetryPolicy policy = new DefaultRetryPolicy(socketTimeOut, 0, DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT);

    stringRequest.setRetryPolicy(policy);

    RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
    queue.add(stringRequest);

}
```

in AppScript>

```js
  function doGet(e)
{
  var action=e.parameter.action;
  if (action=='getMember')
  {
      return getUsers(member_sheet);
  }
}

function getUsers (member_sheet)
{
  member_sheet.activate;
  var jo={};
  var dataArray=[];
  var rows=member_sheet.getRange(2,1,member_sheet.getLastRow()-1,member_sheet.getLastColumn()).getValues();
  for (var i=0,l=rows.length;i<l;i++ )
  {
    var dataRow=rows[i];
    var record={};
    record['id']=dataRow[0];
    record['date']=Utilities.formatDate(dataRow[1],"IST","dd/MMM/YYYY");
    record['name']=dataRow[2];
    record['age']=dataRow[3];
    record['gender']=dataRow[4];
    record['mobile']=dataRow[5];
    record['life']=dataRow[6];
    record['status']=dataRow[7];
    dataArray.push(record);
  }
  jo.user=dataArray;
  var result=JSON.stringify(jo);
  return ContentService.createTextOutput(result).setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.JSON);


}
```

Please guide me. Thank you

Comment: Can you provide a sample implementation on how does it store data into your Google Sheet? Do you use Sheets API? Is the App Script tag relevant to the question?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: sir, I have updated the question by including code. please help...